# DataIntegrityViolationException how to handle using JPA to persist

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, exception

i'm using JpaRepository, JpaSpecificationExecutor to persists my data on Database. My company does not allow us to use hibernate. My problem is this: A need a way to Handle a DataIntegrityViolationException  in 3 cenarios  what are is:

- Violation of a unique key
- Trying to insert NULL value into a column NOT NULL value
- Trying to refering(Foreign Key) a table with column does not exists.
  ....
  My actual solution is:

```
catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        String message = ExceptionUtils.getMessage(e.getRootCause());
                log.error(message);
                if (message.contains("Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK01_grupo_ramo'"))
                    throw new ValidacaoException(StringUtils.getMensagem("produto.exception.grupoRamo.nrGrupoRamoDuplicado", grupoRamo.getNrGrupoRamo()));
```

Comment: I think you should create `ExceptionResolverService` and define in this service which exception should be returned based on the message, where are you using this managing, it is better to have a `ExceptionHandler` which based what exception you might return what you want as well...

Comment: My problem is that JPA returns DataIntegrityViolationException for all three scenarios mentioned above. and I need to customize a user friendly message